# Angularjs: how to set scope variable to null associatd with a block under ng-if gets removed from DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ng-if

I have two radio button Yes and No in my angular view, when user clicks on Yes radio it renders(using ng-if) 3 text inputs ie. Input A, Input B and Input C.

When user clicks No, it renders(again using ng-if) other 3 text inputs ie. Input X, Input Y and Input Z.

All 6 text inputs are associated with 6 different $scope variable using ng-model. Is there any easy/angular way to set the $scope variable to null when user change the selection from Yes to No, or from No to Yes.

I know I can write ng-change on radio button and can set scope variable to null, but I am looking for some automatic way if its possible.

I am looking for something which can reset all scope variables to null when associated(using ng-model) html control gets removed from dom as part of ng-if condition change.

Comment: An automatic way? No, I don't think so. Why are you opposed to writing a simple controller function to do this? It would be much more clear and maintainable long term.

Comment: Actual requirement is quite complex, I have so many such radio buttons, including multi level hierarchy of radio buttons. so I was looking for some auto way rather then writing complex conditions in controller, which can also help me to avoid code change in controller if I change ng-if  condition in view.

Comment: To each their own, but I am a strong believer that complex logic like that has no place in the markup and should be in the code where it can be structured and commented. Imagine another developer coming back in 6 months and trying to unravel that in the markup.